# ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host "danny@server" (1)

Tags: mysql

I am getting Error 2005 while trying to mysqldump from the remote mysql

`mysqldump -u root -pXXX -h danny@server test > test_sep11.sql`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `danny@`. No need to specify a user, this is no ssh connection. The DNS lookup fails otherwise.

```
mysqldump -u root -pXXX -h server test > test_sep11.sql
```

Comment: that gives me another error as "mysqldump: Got error: 2003: "Can't connect to MySQL server on server when trying to connect"

Comment: @Danny is the `bind-address` set to the ip-address of the server? Not to localhost?

Comment: @fancypants thers is no `bind-address` set in /etc/my.cnf

Comment: Add `bind-address 0.0.0.0` under the `[mysqld]` section and restart the server. Also make sure, that there are no typos in your server name.